# Android Alarm doesn't cacnel

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I've found many questions on SO regarding this topic but none could help me, my alarm just doesn't cancel this is my code

set alarm in somclass

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_yes )
    {
        Long time = MainActivity.targetTime.getTimeInMillis();
        int requestID =  IDGenerator.incrementalRequestID(context);
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, SomeTask.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Log.v("conclick", requestID+"");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestID,
                intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time , pendingIntent );
    }
    dismiss();
}
```

cancel it in another

```
public static void cancelAlarm( Context context , int requestID)
{
    Log.v("cancelling", requestID+"");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

- requestID is the same when setting and cancelling

Comment: It's always nice when people vote down without leaving any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be problem
replace this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

to

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, SomeTask.class);
```

it should be like this

```
 public static void cancelAlarm( Context context , int requestID)
    {
        Log.v("cancelling", requestID+"");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, SomeTask.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                requestID, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I figured this out and came to update question and I found your answer, thank you